# Rails does not nest nested posted JSON Object in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, post

I'm posting the following JSON to the rails create method in my 'user_controller' controller class.

```
{"user_detail_attributes": 
    {
    "login":"dan123456",
    "password":"password",
    "password_confirmation":"password"
    },
"surname":"REST_TEST",
"firstname":"REST_TEST",
"phone":"0456782",
"grad_year":2010,
"jobs":false,
"email":"REST_TEST@EMAIL.co.uk"
}
```

My user_params are as follows:

```
params.require(:user).permit(
:surname, :firstname, :phone, :grad_year, :jobs, :email, 
user_detail_attributes: [:id, :password,     :password_confirmation, :login])
```

Rails should then map this json to the user.

So the params variable should contain a user, inside that user should be the attributes **including** the user_detail_attributes.

However the user_detail attributes are appearing outside the user params variable as a completely seperate params variable, on the same level as the users params.

So, what should be happening:

```
user
    +surname
    +firstname
    .
    .
    .
    +user_detail_attributes
        +login
        +password
        +password_confirmation
```

What's actually happening:

```
user_detail_attributes
    +login
    +password
    +password_confirmation
user
    +surname
    +firstname
    .
    .
    .
```

This then leads to the user being mapped to the user table in my database but no user_details being mapped to that table.

Does anyone know why this is happening and whether I can fix it? And if it is something that I need to do with the JSON format or something in the rails application.

Thanks,

Dan

EDIT: Fixed

Comment: can you provide the request to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the problem.

The JSON should be formatted as follows:

```
{"user":
    {"user_detail_attributes": 
        {
        "login":"dan123456",
        "password":"password",
        "password_confirmation":"password"
        },
    "surname":"REST_TEST",
    "firstname":"REST_TEST",
    "phone":"0456782",
    "grad_year":2010,
    "jobs":false,
    "email":"REST_TEST@EMAIL.co.uk"
    }
}
```

I was missing the user attribute at the start as this was how my c# JSON encoder was formatting the JSON from my user and user_detail_attribute classes.

I had a play around by creating the JSON manually and this turned out to be the fix.

Thanks for everyone's help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Strong Parameters Documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters)

You should be doing something like this:

```
parameters.require(:user).permit(:surname, :firstname, :phone, :grad_year, :jobs, :email, {user_detail_attributes: [:login, :password, :password_confirmation] })
```

Note the `{}` before and after the `user_detail_attributes`

**My test in console**

```
hash = {user: {user_detail_attributes: { login: "dan123456", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password"}, surname:"REST_TEST", firstname:"REST_TEST", phone:"0456782", grad_year:2010, jobs:false, email:"REST_TEST@EMAIL.co.uk"} }

params =  ActionController::Parameters.new(params)

parameters.require(:user).permit(:surname, :firstname, :phone, :grad_year, :jobs, :email, {user_detail_attributes: [:login, :password, :password_confirmation] })
```

Outuput:

```
 {"surname"=>"REST_TEST", "firstname"=>"REST_TEST", "phone"=>"0456782", "grad_year"=>2010, "jobs"=>false, "email"=>"REST_TEST@EMAIL.co.uk", "user_detail_attributes"=>{"login"=>"dan123456", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password"}}
```

Comment: I've added those brackets but it hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately. The user_detail_attributes are still not nested inside user.

Comment: Strange. I've updated my answer with the test I made. It's working here.

Comment: I also have a webpage where I can post a form to it, the user_detail_attributes nest correctly when I use for form (and did before the brackets), but using the JSON which I describe above they don't.